# Add legend to d3 scatterplot matrix

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to add a legend to a d3 scatterplot matrix (using this example as a template: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663), and while the scatterplot itself is displaying as expected, I have been unable to successfully add a legend. The code for the plot and one of the attempts at adding a legend are below:

```
var width = 960,
size = 150,
padding = 19.5;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([padding / 2, size - padding / 2]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([size - padding / 2, padding / 2]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(5);

var color = d3.scale.category10();





d3.csv(datafilename, function(error, dataset) {
  var domainByTrait = {},
      traits = d3.keys(dataset[0]).filter(function(d) { return d !== "class"; }),
      n = traits.length;

  traits.forEach(function(trait) {
    domainByTrait[trait] = d3.extent(dataset, function(d) { return d[trait]; });
  });

  xAxis.tickSize(size * n);
  yAxis.tickSize(-size * n);

  var brush = d3.svg.brush()
      .x(x)
      .y(y)
      .on("brushstart", brushstart)
      .on("brush", brushmove)
      .on("brushend", brushend);

  var svg = d3.select("#visualizationDiv").append("svg")
      .attr("width", size * n + padding)
      .attr("height", size * n + padding)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + "," + padding / 2 + ")");

  svg.selectAll(".x.axis")
      .data(traits)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + (n - i - 1) * size + ",0)"; })
      .each(function(d) { x.domain(domainByTrait[d]); d3.select(this).call(xAxis); });

  svg.selectAll(".y.axis")
      .data(traits)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * size + ")"; })
      .each(function(d) { y.domain(domainByTrait[d]); d3.select(this).call(yAxis); });

  var cell = svg.selectAll(".cell")
      .data(cross(traits, traits))
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "cell")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (n - d.i - 1) * size + "," + d.j * size + ")"; })
      .each(plot);

  // Titles for the diagonal.
  cell.filter(function(d) { return d.i === d.j; }).append("text")
      .attr("x", padding)
      .attr("y", padding)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.x; });

  cell.call(brush);

  function plot(p) {
    var cell = d3.select(this);

    x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
    y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);

    cell.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "frame")
        .attr("x", padding / 2)
        .attr("y", padding / 2)
        .attr("width", size - padding)
        .attr("height", size - padding);

    cell.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[p.x]); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d[p.y]); })
        .attr("r", 3)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.class); });
  }

  var brushCell;

  // Clear the previously-active brush, if any.
  function brushstart(p) {
    if (brushCell !== this) {
      d3.select(brushCell).call(brush.clear());
      x.domain(domainByTrait[p.x]);
      y.domain(domainByTrait[p.y]);
      brushCell = this;
    }
  }

  // Highlight the selected circles.
  function brushmove(p) {
    var e = brush.extent();
    svg.selectAll("circle").classed("hidden", function(d) {
      return e[0][0] > d[p.x] || d[p.x] > e[1][0]
          || e[0][1] > d[p.y] || d[p.y] > e[1][1];
    });
  }

  // If the brush is empty, select all circles.
  function brushend() {
    if (brush.empty()) svg.selectAll(".hidden").classed("hidden", false);
  }

  function cross(a, b) {
    var c = [], n = a.length, m = b.length, i, j;
    for (i = -1; ++i < n;) for (j = -1; ++j < m;) c.push({x: a[i], i: i, y: b[j], j: j});
    return c;
  }

  d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", size * n + padding + 20 + "px");








// add legend   
var legend = svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "legend")
       .attr("height", 100)
       .attr("width", 100)
       .attr('transform', 'translate(-20,50)');    


legend.selectAll('rect')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 65)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20;})
  .attr("width", 10)
  .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.class); });

legend.selectAll('text')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 52)
  .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i *  20 + 9;})
  .text(function(d) { return d.class; });

});
```

Among my other unsuccessful attempts at adding a legend are

```
 var legend = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(dataset)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

 legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 28)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.class); });

 legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 34)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d.class; });
```

and

```
 var legend = svg.selectAll('g').data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr("class", "legend");

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 45)
  .attr("y", 25)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("width", 50)
  .each(function(d, i) {
    var g = d3.select(this);
    g.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 65)
      .attr("y", i*25)
      .attr("width", 10)
      .attr("height", 10)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.class); });

    g.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 50)
      .attr("y", i * 25 + 8)
      .attr("height",30)
      .attr("width",100)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.class); })
      .text(function(d) { return d.class; });
```

all based on examples I've found on the web. None of these approaches seem to be working - I must be missing something here. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is right at the beginning:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll('g').data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr("class", "legend");
```

The `selectAll('g')` is going to select one of the groups already in your diagram, and then nothing will happen because `enter()` indicates that everything from there on (including the value that gets saved to the `legend` variable) only applies to groups that don't exist yet.

I'm pretty sure this legend code is supposed to be run from *within its own `<g>` element*.  That way, it won't interfere with the rest of your graph.

```
var legendGroup = svg.append('g')
                     .attr('class', 'legend')
                     .attr('transform', /* translate as appropriate */);

var legendEntry = legendGroup.selectAll('g')
                     .data(dataset);  
          //create one legend entry for each series in the dataset array
          //if that's not what you want, create an array that has one 
          //value for every entry you want in the legend

legendEntry.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend-entry")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });
            //shift each entry down by approx 1 line (20px)

legendEntry.append("rect") //add a square to each entry
      /* and so on */
```

Comment: Can you give your sample code with the Iris dataset if you want the legend to relate color to species? It is still not clear to me what to enter where you have comments